# Change in beat frequency in isochronic tones in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning about [isochronic tones](https://thedynamicstate.wordpress.com/2016/12/24/creating-isochronic-tones-with-audacity/) and started writing a basic python script to generate the same. Following is a script that I have written for doing the following:

- Generate a trapezoidal wave of beat frequency
- Modulate a sine wave of base frequency, with the trapezoidal wave of beat frequency

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  # encoding: utf-8

  """
  Small program for creating Isochronic Tones of desired base frequency, beat frequency and ramp frequencies
  """

  import math
  import wave
  import struct
  import array
  import sys

  def make_isochronic_wave(beat_freq, beat_ramp_percent, beat_sampl_rate, beat_time, base_freq, amplitude):

  #
  # The time for which the trapezoidal beat frequency wave is present in the entire cycle
  #
  up_time = 1 / beat_freq

  #
  # Gap between consequtive trapezoidal beats
  #
  gap_percent = up_time * 0.15

  #
  # To accomodate gaps
  #
  up_time = up_time * 0.85

  #
  # Total number of samples
  #
  data_size = beat_sampl_rate * beat_time

  #
  # No. of gaps per sec = No. of beats per sec
  #
  no_of_gaps = beat_freq

  #
  # Samples per gap = percentage of total time allocated for gaps * No. of samples per sec
  #
  sampls_per_gap = gap_percent * beat_sampl_rate

  #
  # Total number of samples in all the gaps
  #
  gap_sampls = no_of_gaps * sampls_per_gap

  #
  # Change the beat sample rate to accomodate gaps
  #
  beat_sampl_rate = beat_sampl_rate - gap_sampls

  #
  # nsps = Number of Samples Per Second
  #
  # NOTE: Please see the image at: 
  #
  beat_nsps_defined = beat_sampl_rate * up_time

  beat_nsps_inc = beat_nsps_defined * beat_ramp_percent

  beat_nsps_dec = beat_nsps_defined * beat_ramp_percent

  beat_nsps_stable = beat_nsps_defined - (beat_nsps_inc + beat_nsps_dec)

  beat_nsps_undefined = beat_sampl_rate - beat_nsps_defined

  #
  # Trapezoidal values
  #
  values = []

  #
  # Trapezoidal * sine == Isochronic values
  #
  isoch_values = []

  #
  # Samples constructed
  #
  sampls_const = 0

  #
  # Iterate till all the samples in data_size are constructed
  #
  while sampls_const < data_size:
      prev_sampl_value_inc = 0.0
      prev_sampl_value_dec = 1.0
      #
      # Construct one trapezoidal beat wave (remember this is not the entire sample)
      #
      for sampl_itr in range(0, int(beat_sampl_rate)):
          if sampl_itr < beat_nsps_inc:
              value = prev_sampl_value_inc + (1 / beat_nsps_inc)
              prev_sampl_value_inc = value
              values.append(value)
          if sampl_itr > beat_nsps_inc:
              if sampl_itr < (beat_nsps_inc + beat_nsps_stable):
                  value = 1
                  values.append(value)
              elif (sampl_itr > (beat_nsps_inc + beat_nsps_stable)) and (sampl_itr < (beat_nsps_inc + beat_nsps_stable + beat_nsps_dec)):
                  value = prev_sampl_value_dec - (1 / beat_nsps_dec)
                  prev_sampl_value_dec = value
                  values.append(value)

      #
      # Add the gap cycles
      #
      for gap_iter in range(0, int(sampls_per_gap)):
          values.append(0)

      #
      # Increment the number of samples constructed to reflect the values
      #
      sampls_const = sampls_const + beat_nsps_defined + gap_sampls

  #
  # Open the wave file
  #
  wav_file = wave.open("beat_wave_%s_%s.wav" % (base_freq, beat_freq), "w")

  #
  # Define parameters
  #
  nchannels = 2
  sampwidth = 2
  framerate = beat_sampl_rate
  nframes = data_size
  comptype = "NONE"
  compname = "not compressed"

  wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname))

  #
  # Calculate isochronic wave point values
  #
  value_iter = 0

  for value in values:
      isoch_value = value * math.sin(2 * math.pi * base_freq * (value_iter / beat_sampl_rate))
      value_iter = value_iter + 1
      isoch_values.append(isoch_value)

  #
  # Create the wave file (in .wav format)
  #
  for value in isoch_values:
      data = array.array('h')
      data.append(int(value * amplitude / 2)) # left channel
      data.append(int(value * amplitude / 2)) # right channel

      wav_file.writeframes(data.tostring())


  wav_file.close()

  try:
      base_freq = int(sys.argv[1], 10)
      beat_freq = int(sys.argv[2], 10)
      sample_rate = int(sys.argv[3], 10)
      output_time = int(sys.argv[4], 10)
      ramp_percent = float(sys.argv[5])
      amplitude = float(sys.argv[6])

      make_isochronic_wave(beat_freq, ramp_percent, sample_rate, output_time, base_freq, amplitude)
  except:
      msg = """
  <program> <base freqency> <beat frequency> <sample rate> <output time> <ramp percent> <amplitude>
  """
      print (msg)
  ```

The above code works fine, and I get a wave of the below format:

[image: Generated Isochronic Tones]

The above format being similar to what is generated using audacity using IsoMod plugin. However, I would like to generate a tone which has the beat frequency reduce as a ramp. For this, I have enhanced the above script to call the trapezoidal wave generation in a loop, once every second. However, setting the parameters for wav file for writing multiple times (with changes in data_size due to change in beat_freq across the ramp), I am getting the following error

```
G:\>python gen_isochronic_tones.py 70 10 5 11025 5 0.15 8000
gen_isochronic_tones.py:195: DeprecationWarning: tostring() is deprecated. Use tobytes() instead.
  make_isochronic_wave(beat_freq_start, beat_freq_end, ramp_percent, sample_rate, output_time, base_freq, amplitude)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen_isochronic_tones.py", line 195, in <module>
    make_isochronic_wave(beat_freq_start, beat_freq_end, ramp_percent, sample_rate, output_time, base_freq, amplitude)
  File "gen_isochronic_tones.py", line 156, in make_isochronic_wave
    wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, data_size, comptype, compname))
  File "G:\Python37-32\lib\wave.py", line 399, in setparams
    raise Error('cannot change parameters after starting to write')
wave.Error: cannot change parameters after starting to write
```

Looks like wave module allows the paramters (namely data_size above) to be changed only once. Any idea how to make this work for changing data_size?